# Delete all text between two delimiters in for all elements in a list of strings python

Tags: python, html, parsing

My list holds strings that are representing info on html tables, I want to  delete the extra info in the tags
ie. this is what is in there initially

```
<td style="color: red;">
```

and this is what I want to get
    `<td>`

so far I've tried this where table is my list of strings

```
[re.sub(r'<td[.*?]>','<td>',x,re.DOTALL) for x in tables]
```

pulling my hair out over this and I know it's something thats an easy fix can anyone give suggestions?

Thanks!

and yes I do need to use regular expressions and am not expected to use any extra html imports...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/57191

Comment: If you really want to use regular expressions, try: `re.sub(r'<td.*?>', '<td>', x, re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Use `re.sub('<td[^>]+>', '<td>', x)` for maximum safety if you really *need* to use regular expressions.